# How memory is allocated to kernel?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, kernel

When a process running in user mode requests additional memory, pages are allocated from a list of free page frames maintained by the kernel.
But, Who allocates memory to the kernel?
How it is allocated? Is there a memory wastage in allocation of memory to kernel?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel is what is responsible for allocating memory to user applications (at a high level), so it can just as easily allocate memory to itself.

Just as there is typically a memory allocator used by user applications (e.g, `malloc()` in libc), there is also a memory allocator within most kernels (e.g, `kmalloc()` in the Linux kernel). Since it must operate under different constraints than a userspace allocator, it may be implemented somewhat differently.